# Как передать изображения в цикл?

Tags: java, загрузка

Доброго времени суток)

Нужно загрузить 6 изображений и передать их в цикл. Для загрузки используется класс LoadImage.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException 
    {
        IRExamenator examenator = new IRExamenator();

        //тут надо считать картинки и передать их в цикл ниже

        for (String path : args)
        {

        }
```

Класс для загрузки изображений.

```
public class LoadImage {

    public static BufferedImage image(String path) throws Exception{

        return ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    }
}
```

То как загрузить изображение я примерно понимаю

```
BufferedImage img = LoadImage.image("Images\\1.bmp");
```

Но как потом их передать в этот массив `args` нет((

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Редактирую:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException //too many code under try-catch for non-handling situation (always exit on exception)
    {

        IRExamenator examenator = new IRExamenator();

        //тут надо считать картинки и передать их в цикл ниже
        String[] path = {
                "etalons/etalon-forest-1.png",
                "etalons/etalon-forest-2.png",
                "etalons/etalon-ground-1.png",
                "etalons/etalon-ground-2.png",
                "etalons/etalon-water-1.png",
                "etalons/etalon-water-2.png"

         };

        BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[path.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            images[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(path[i]));
        }

        for (String path : images)
        {
            int[][] mas = IRUtil.imageToMatrix(IRUtil.loadImage(path)); // лоадИмейдж принимает путь к картинке
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я вижу два варианта:

1. Вы знаете пути всех шести изображений на этапе компиляции. Тогда просто вызываете метод `ImageIO.read` для каждого пути, получаете массив изображений, что с ними дальше делать уже вам решать.

   ```
   import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           String[] pathes = {
                   "path1/image1.png",
                   "path2/image2.jpg",
                    ...
            };

           BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[pathes.length];
           for (int i = 0; i < pathes.length; i++) {
               images[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(pathes[i]));
           }

           // далее делаете с массивом images что хотите
       }
   }
   ```
2. На этапе компиляции пути изображений неизвестны. Можно считывать их из стандартного входа, либо надеяться что пользователь передаст их аргументами командной строки, и они окажутся в массиве `args` (Это аргумент метода `main`). Тогда надо в предыдущем решении изменить инициализацию переменной `pathes`:

   ```
   import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
   import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.IOException;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
           String[] pathes = args;

           BufferedImage[] images = new BufferedImage[pathes.length];
           for (int i = 0; i < pathes.length; i++) {
               images[i] = ImageIO.read(new File(pathes[i]));
           }

           // далее делаете с массивом images что хотите
       }
   }
   ```

Замечание: в коде выше не используется класс `LoadImage`, мне кажется, что он бесполезен, по сути он является обёрткой над методом `ImageIO.read`.

Comment: ничего не хочет работать))

Comment: @ДашаНовикова, можете, пожалуйста, подробнее описать что именно не работает?
 Не компилируется, или компилируется, но при запуске возникает ошибка? Если ошибка, то вам стоит отправить нам её текст.

Comment: я отредактировала

Comment: если редактировать по вашему примеру, то что нужно писать в скобки после for?

Comment: Расскажите, пожалуйста, что вы вообще хотите сделать с этими изображениями. У вас какой-то новый класс `IRUtil` появился. Если он принимает путь к изображению, то тогда замените цикл `for (String path : images)` на `for (String path : pathes)`.